# CakePHP 3 Theme change at runtime

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm begin with work with CakePHP 3 Themes. I know i can set Themes in the AppController  in the beforeRender function of the Project with

`$this->viewBuilder()->theme('ThemeName');`

but now i want a button in my view to change the theme. I have this in my view

`<?= $this->Html->link(('changeTheme'), ['action' => 'changeTheme']) ?>`

and the function in my controller but what i must do to change the theme in the controller or generell at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i fix this problem with a cookie. The cookie save a variable of a theme and in a if query in the beforeRender function do the action.

Comment: You could alternately use a session variable for it, but the cookie method should be fine.